# How can I see what visitors are searching for?

Tags: 6, search

Are visitor search terms stored somewhere in Drupal 6? I see a **search_total** table that might hold that info but the data in there looks kinda weird.

I'm using search module in core.

Comment: are you opposed to using Google Analytics to track this?

Comment: I want to know what people were searching for on my site. Found a report that seems to give me what I need at /admin/reports/search

Comment: Where does the data for /admin/reports/search come from?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's pretty limited.

View top search phrases (in Drupal 6.x):
yoursite.com/admin/reports/search

The data originates from the *watchdog* table, which means that how much data is provided depends on how far back your watchdog data goes (usually not far).

The [Search Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_log) module will provide more robust results. Or use Google Analytics, as the commenter above suggested.

Answer (score 0):

We use Piwik Analytics for this. piwik.org